# How to decode LONGTEXT/TEXT type in swift

Tags: mysql, swift, decode, jsondecoder, longtext

anyone know how to decode a mysql 'LONGTEXT' or 'TEXT' type in swift?

I'm using nodejs get data from mysql and expose it as REST API, and call the API from my swift code. the problem is swift can't decode 'background' and 'notes', it's working if i remove these two columns from the Vote struct

The database table 'vote', the structure is like :

```
CREATE TABLE `vote` (
  `createdAt` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `background` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `highestScore` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the json format is like

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "IQ Test",
"thumbnail": "eddie",
"background": "This is a typical IQ test",
"amount": 33,
"type": "score",
"highestScore": 174
}]
```

my code in swift is:

```
struct Vote: Codable {
var id: Int
var name: String
var thumbnail: String
var background: String
var notes: String 
var amount: Double
var type: String
var highestScore: Double

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case name
    case thumbnail
    case background
    case notes
    case amount
    case type
    case highestScore
    
}
```

}

the decode piece is like:

```
if let data = data {
    if let votes = try? jsonDecoder.decode([Vote].self, from: data) {
        completion(votes)
    }
} else {
    completion(nil)
}
```

Comment: Columns that can be NULL should be declared as optionals in the struct, like `var background: String?`

Comment: hi Eric,  thank you, turns out I have a column has no value, this is why decode nothing in swift. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Danny, I have run your code and get an optimized way as follows:-**

*Construct the model structure like this:-*

```
// MARK: - CourseElement
struct VoteElement: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name, thumbnail, background: String?
    let amount: Int?
    let type: String?
    let highestScore: Int?
}

typealias Vote = [VoteElement]
```

*Use the above structure in the network calls like this:-*

```
if let data = data {
  if let votes = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Vote.self, from: data) {
        completion(votes)
    }
} else {
    completion(nil)
}
```